# "wrong model type for regression" when attempting multinomial model with caret

Tags: r, regression, r-caret

Tried running this code multiple different times and in different ways but still getting error.

```
library(caret)

model_multinom <- train(
  Group ~ GPA + GMAT, 
  data = train_data,
  method = "multinom", 
  trControl = trainControl(method = "none"), 
  preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
  na.action = na.omit
)

# Error: wrong model type for regression
```

Comment: A multinomial model (like your `method = "multinom"`) is a classification model for categorical data, as opposed to a regression model for continuous data. Based on the error, I'm going to guess that the class of your `Group` column is numeric, so caret thinks you need to do regression, not classification. If you want to do classification on that column, you may need to turn it into a `factor` class, try `train_data$Group = factor(train_data$Group)`.

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted a little bit of sample data - `dput(train_data[1:10, ])` is the nicest way to share sample data, this will create copy/pasteable code to reproduce the first 10 rows of your data. It would also help if you would briefly describe what model you're trying to fit, otherwise we don't know if your code is doing what you want it to do or not.